# Magento 2.2.5 extensions conflict (Solved)

Tags: magento-2.2.5, registration

I've a problem with two extensions. One is for add custom registration fields, another is for customer approval. When new customer try to create new account and click on create account, account will be created but on page get http error 500. How can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: hi @Antonio can you please elaborate more. It will be easier to answer if you can post what exactly you did so far.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some logs? exception, system, nginx(?) error logs

Comment: Can you give a try to sequence in your custom extensions module.xml file if it helps..

Comment: Have you read log file of magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with changing extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: redirectPath in /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php on line 296

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: redirectPath in /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php on line 296

 #0 /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php(296): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/m...', 296, Array)

 #1 /var/www/html/magentomonster/generated/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php(24): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost->execute()

 #2 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->execute()

 #3 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #4 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

 #5 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #6 /var/www/html/magentomonster/generated/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php(143): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

 #7 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Itoris\RegFields\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #8 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #9 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

 #10 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #11 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #12 /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/TemplateMonster/LayoutSwitcher/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #13 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): TemplateMonster\LayoutSwitcher\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #14 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #15 /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/TemplateMonster/SiteMaintenance/Model/PageCache/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(34): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #16 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): TemplateMonster\SiteMaintenance\Model\PageCache\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #17 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #18 /var/www/html/magentomonster/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)

 #19 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

 #20 /var/www/html/magentomonster/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

 #21 /var/www/html/magentomonster/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()

 #22 /var/www/html/magentomonster/index.php(43): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))

 #23 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: redirectPath in
>   /var/www/html/magentomonster/app/code/Itoris/RegFields/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
>   on line 296

Please check the $redirectPath on the line 296, make sure this variable was defined before

Comment: Yes, its defined because without other extension it works. This exception happens when I install customer activation extension.

Comment: ok now it is working ?

Comment: No, i can't find a solution.

Comment: Let try change $redirectPath -> @$redirectPath then check result